# How do you sql-sync a site with multiple databases?

Tags: drush

I have a site that uses two databases.  I would like to sql-sync both of those databases to the development version of the site. Is this possible?

```
// Default
drush sql-sync @prod @dev 

// Optional?
drush sql-sync @prod @dev --database=my_other_db
```

Answer (score 3):

```
drush sql-sync @prod @dev --source-database=my_other_db --target-database=my_other_db
```